# What is the correct punctuation Of the following statement

Tags: punctuation

Is **;** rightly placed in the following sentence or not?

> He is a nice boy; however, he had been rude last evening

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please can you be more specific on what you are unsure about in this sentence? Questions along the lines of "correct the punctuation/phrasing" are strictly off topic.  Please feel free to review the [ELL help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to find out more about how to ask for help

Comment: I wanna ask if ; is rightly placed or not.